# How do I get a green tag in clash of clans in the newest update of 2015

Tags: clash-of-clans

In clash of clans I'm in a clan that does lots of wars. But the leader tried putting me in the war but can't because I have a red shield (it shows on the far left on a name tag).

How would I get a green shield?

Answer (score 0):

Open your chat in game. Then click the blue `i` icon in the top right area of the chat. Then click the My Profile tab in the top left corner. You should see a red icon that reads "Clan Wars". That should be green. Tap it and confirm your "I'm in" status.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. Clan leaders can include people in wars even if they have opted out. I suspect that the OP is simply not yet eligible for war since the clan leader was unable to include them, but it is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you left a clan while you were part of that clan's war, you will be inelgible for clan wars for a certain amount of time, which is probably equal to the amount of time the war has left till the end. Browse your clan members and find yourself, where there might be a grey shield. Anyone that has a grey shield is automatically put as a red sheild and cannot be forced to participate in war.